# how to show thumbnil image from youtube rss feed in iphone

Tags: iphone, rss, youtube

I tried To Parse the response of the of the youtube RSS feed and displayed it in tableview... 
I works fine except i can't fetch URL for the thumbnil image of the video from rss... It comes in description tag and inside description tag there is a whole div (html)... is there any simpler way example tutorial.....to fetch the thumbnil image from youtube rss...

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about from the RSS feed, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same prob ,but have figured out with YOUtube API ,

make your feed url in this pattern

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/[INSERT USERNAME]/uploads

after in the generated xml there is a media:thumnail tag where u can used to display youtube thumnails images.

without using this format u will get a descr tag with div style image thumbnail quite hard to parse as it is a html part,

better try this,i have solved this using type of feed pattern